# How to return the result of a function to main that should replace one string with a new one

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am trying to solve a problem in C whereby I get a string and convert some parts of the string to numbers. I have created a function called replace. In the function I iterate through the string array seeking the specific vowels and returning a number instead. The result should be the new string. I should then call the function in main that should show the result. I am a biginner in c and we have not covered other solutions other than using arrays and functions.

However my code returns null. Can someone help me out please? I have now resulted to guess work, having no clue what I need to do and been on it for hours...

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string replace(string argv[]);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // argv[1] is the first word at the command line
    string s;
    string result = 0;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s word\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Word is: %s\n", argv[1]);
        printf("%s\n", result);
        return 0;
    }
}

string replace(string argv[])
{
    string s = argv[1];
    int len = strlen(s);
    string result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'a')
        {
            result += 6;
        }
        else if (s[i] == 'e' )
        {
            result += 3;
        }
        else if (s[i] == 'i')
        {
            result +=  0;
        }
        else if (s[i] == 'u')
        {
            result += 'u';
        }
        else
        {
            result += s[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have tried checking my code and various options to return the string. I have tried using edge chat GPT to figure out the issue in my code,  but I can't solve the issue and the code and now I am truly confused even to the logic of calling functions and using command line arguments....

Comment: What does `printf("%s\n", result);` output? Given that you are passing a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: It's unclear what the `replace()` function is supposed to be doing. It is adding a numeric value or a character value to a `NULL` pointer, and `result +=  0;` does nothing.

Comment: `result += 3;` With this definition `string result = 0;` this is doing pointer arithmetics on a `NULL` pointer. Using pointer arithmetics is only allowed for pointers actually pointing to a valid data object. The result is not a valid string. And BTW: Wherever that pointer might point to afterwards, there will not be any useful string.

Comment: @Gerhardh - Firstly, thanks for responding. I am trying to go through the string array and to replace the given vowels with a number and then to  replace the string with a new one consisting of the replaced vowels. We have not learnt about allocating memory at this stage, it is the second week of cs50, so not familiar with malloc.  But I am wondering about calling the function. It is what I tried to do in my code with. Why does that not work?       
        result = replace(argv);
        printf("%s\n", result);

Comment: You don't move through any array. If you want to move through your input string, then you need to assign that address to your `result` pointer. Or directly use the input variable. But you also don't modify any content of the array but you only modify the pointer. To access elements in an array, use `result[index]`, assuming `index` holds the correct position in the array. You know how to access an array with `s[i]`. Why don't you do it similar with `result`?

Comment: @Gerhardh - I used the code your proposed and it worked, but it was really copy and waste, which is not the point. I am just wondering if we have not been introduced to allocating memory or using stdlib.h or concepts like size_t len, if the problem would be even possible to solve for a beginner without the advanced stuff.  It feels daunting to get a lab with challenges that require so much know-how. Do you know of an alternative that migh have worked? I tried going with    string s = argv[1];
    int len = strlen(s);
    string result = "";   but I got a segmentation fault(core dumped)

Comment: I do not know your assignment. Maybe you should just modify the string in place. That means you do not make a copy of the string but take the string you got and modify the characters in the location where they are. CS50 uses that bs `string` type to hide pointers from you. It actually is a `char*` with all its limitation and side effects. They do this probably because they think, you are not yet ready for that rabbit hole. But they really should tell you that you cannot just copy such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

`result += 3; result += 'u';` etc do not add anything to the string. It is not C++, Python or PHP.

`string` is just a `typedef` hiding pointer to char.

To create a new string you need to allocate enough memory to accommodate all the characters and null character terminator.

It is very hard to understand what `result += 3` suppose to do - I will assume that you want to concatenate it with `"3"`.

```
string replace(string argv[])
{
    string s = argv[1];
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    string result = malloc(len + 1);
    if(result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] == 'a')
            {
                result[i] = '6';
            }
            else if (s[i] == 'e' )
            {
                result[i] = '3';
            }
            else if (s[i] == 'i')
            {
                result[i] = '0';
            }
            else if (s[i] == 'u')
            {
                result[i] = 'u'; // for what reason?? (same as OP code)
            }
            else
            {
                result[i] = s[i];
            }
        }
        result[len] = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But you never call this function. Yoe need to:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // argv[1] is the first word at the command line
    string s;
    string result;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s word\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Word is: %s\n", argv[1]);
        result = replace(argv);
        if(result) printf("%s\n", result);
        else {/* handle allocation error*/}
        free(result);
        return 0;
    }
}
```